# Any downsides to using image src without protocol?

Tags: html, image, ssl, protocols

Basically, I am wanting to switch to SSL, and maybe 1 day the site might not have SSL, so will need to downgrade to using `http:` protocol if needed without too much trouble.  Am wondering if I use this approach for images will it be ok?  And if there are any downsides for this?

```
<img src="//path/to/image.jpg" />
```

And

```
<img src="//another.site.com/images/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

This seems to work fine, just wondering if there are any downsides for images without protocols in browsers, or otherwise?

Thanks